# Turn off CouchDb's _changes API

Tags: couchdb

If I don't need _changes functionality, can I turn it off? Because, if I understand correctly, it will eat some additional space. For example, in MongoDb I can enable/disable oplog.

Comment: Probably deletion of httpd_db_handlers/_changes config key might unmount _changes endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronization is one of the main features of CouchDB which is based on the _changes functionality.

This is a core feature in CouchDB that can not be disabled.